# works in IDLE but not the command prompt

Tags: python

This code works in IDLE but not in the commandline. Why the difference?

```
poem = 'poem.txt'

f = file(poem)
while True:
    line = f.readline()
    if len(line) == 0:
        break
    print line,
f.close()
```

The `poem.txt` file exists (it is a string). The shell output is this:

```
"Programming is fun When the work is done if you wanna make your work also fun: use Python!"
```

The commandline output is this:

```
"No such file or directory: 'poem.txt'"
```

The `poem.txt` file is in the same folder as the `.py` file. What is going wrong here?

Comment: Can you try using `./poem.txt` instead of `poem.txt`

Comment: How are you invoking your python script from the command line, can you provide an example?

Comment: @EknathIyer--wont that cause the pointer to go one folder up int he directory?

Comment: @DRH--`C:/Users/Python/filepractice.py` `Enter`

Comment: @codeninja: "wont that cause the pointer to go one folder up"?  No.  `.` is Linux for "This Directory".  `..` is the parent directory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you are not RUNNING the python script from the same directory as the poem.txt is in. Verify this by putting:

```
import os
print os.getcwd()
```

in your script.

#### Update

It seems like I was right. When you run: `C:/Users/Python/filepractice.py` the current working directory is the directory you are running it from, not the directory where filepractice.py is.

If you do this in cmd.exe

```
c:
cd \Users\Python
python filepractice.py
```

it would probably work.

Answer (score -1):

Try opening a command prompt window in the same directory, type the command:

"cd [current directory]" and then "python [yourfile].py"